# Links in Modal not working for Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is a very puzzling issue, but all the links I have in the below modal do not work (clicking on the links, nothing happens). I just want it to open the href to the correct page.  Any help would be appreciated. The code is below:

Information

```
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">US Citizenship Quiz</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                Small sampling of the US Citizenship Test built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <a href="https://bgalladian.github.io/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Site</a>
                                        <a href="https://github.com/bgalladian/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End of Modal -->
```

EDIT: Added entire code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

 <title>Bedig Galladian</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-v=2.1.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/ihover.css" rel="stylesheet">


 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,300,200&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


 <link rel="prefetch" href="images/zoom.png">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
  <div class="container">

   <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>


   <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav row">
     <li data-slide="1" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-1" href="#slide-1" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-home"></span> <span class="text">HOME</span></a></li>
     <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-2" href="#slide-2" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-user"></span> <span class="text">ABOUT ME</span></a></li>
     <li data-slide="7" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-7" href="#slide-7" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-briefcase"></span> <span class="text">PORTFOLIO</span></a></li>
     <li data-slide="4" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-4" href="#slide-4" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-gears"></span> <span class="text">SKILLS</span></a></li>
     <li data-slide="5" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-5" href="#slide-5" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-file"></span> <span class="text">RESUME</span></a></li>
     <li data-slide="6" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-6" href="#slide-6" title="Next Section"><span class="icon icon-envelope"></span> <span class="text">CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2 active-menu"></div>
    </div>
   </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
 </div><!-- /.navbar -->


 <!-- === Arrows === -->
 <div id="arrows">
  <div id="arrow-up" class="disabled"></div>
  <div id="arrow-down"></div>
  <div id="arrow-left" class="disabled visible-lg"></div>
  <div id="arrow-right" class="disabled visible-lg"></div>
 </div><!-- /.arrows -->


 <!-- === MAIN Background === -->
 <div class="slide story" id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="home-row-1" class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h1 class="font-semibold">Bedig <span class="font-thin">Galladian</span></h1>
     <h4 class="font-thin">I am a <span class="font-semibold">Full Stack Web Developer</span></h4>
     <br>
     <br>
    </div><!-- /col-12 -->
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div id="home-row-2" class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6"><span>PROFESSIONAL</span></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6"><span>PERSONABLE</span></div>
    <!-- <div class="col-12 col-sm-4"><span>SUITABLE</span></div> -->
   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /slide1 -->

 <!-- === Slide 2 === -->
 <div class="slide story" id="slide-2" data-slide="2">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row title-row">
    <div class="col-12 font-thin">About <span class="font-semibold">Me</span></div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row line-row">
    <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row subtitle-row">
    <div class="col-12 font-thin">Knower of <span class="font-semibold">useless facts</span></div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row content-row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <p><i class="icon-book"></i></p>
     <h2 class="font-thin">How I Was <span class="font-semibold">Educated</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">I graduated from Towson University in 2012 with my Masters in Student Affairs and Higher Education Administration. After many years of advising students, I decided to that one of my hobbies (web development) is something I would like to pursue.  Hence why enrolled in General Assemblys Web Immersive Program!  </h4>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <p><i class="icon icon-laptop"></i></p>
     <h2 class="font-thin">My Personal <span class="font-semibold">Skills</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">As a former Student Affairs professional, I have leadership and collaboration skills as well as creativity.  I also possess strong interpersonal and social communication skills and can interact with supervisors, coworkers, and clients alike to achieve a desired product.  I have a strong detail focus, and can work well under pressure.
</h4>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
     <p><i class="icon icon-smile"></i></p>
     <h2 class="font-thin">What I Do For <span class="font-semibold">Fun</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">I love to learn and be creative, which is what web development has done for me. Other than coding, I love to research various historical events, and watch movies constantly.  Netflix is always on in my home. I hope to write sreenplay one day.  My perfect day is a set of Legos to build with and a good movie on the TV.  Avid sneakerhead.</h4>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->

   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /slide2 -->

 <!-- === SLide 3 - Portfolio -->
  <div class="slide story" id="slide-7" data-slide="7">
   <div class="row align-items-">

    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row title-row">
      <div class="col-12 font-thin">My  <span class="font-semibold">Portfolio</span></div>
     </div><!-- /row -->
     <div class="row line-row">
      <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
     </div><!-- /row -->
     <div class="row subtitle-row">
      <div class="col-12 font-thin">Take a look at some of my work</span></div>
     </div><!-- /row -->

     <div class="row content-row">

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-">
       <a href="http://www.bgallad.com/project-01/"><img src="images/ucq.png"></a>
       <h2 class="font-thin"><span class="font-semibold">US Citzenship Quiz</span></h2>

      <!-- Modal Button -->
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
         Information
       </button>

       <!-- Modal -->
       <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">US Citizenship Quiz</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               Small sampling of the US Citizenship Test built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
           <a href="https://bgalladian.github.io/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="blank">Go to Site</a>
           <a href="https://github.com/bgalladian/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <!-- End of Modal -->

      </div><!-- /col12 -->

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
       <a href="http://wasitworthit.herokuapp.com"><img src="images/wasitworthit.png"></a>
       <h2 class="font-thin"><span class="font-semibold">Was It It Worth It?</span></h2>

       <!-- Modal Button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1">
          Information
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Was It Worth It?</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
            A movie review app with a "unique" ranking system.  Built with Ruby on Rails, with 3 models, a seach function, and user authentication.  Built over the course of 3 days.

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="https://wasitworthit.herokuapp.com/" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Site</a>
            <a href="https://github.com/bgalladian/project-02" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Modal -->

      </div><!-- /col12 -->

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
       <a href="https://sdkclements.github.io/oneShotFront/"><img src="images/oneShot.png"></a>
       <h2 class="font-thin"><span class="font-semibold">oneShot</span></h2>

        <!-- Modal Button -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
          Information
         </button>

         <!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">oneShot</h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             My first project with a team.  Built with a Rails backend with an Angular frontend.  It is an anonymous message board with no delete or edit function.  Hence the user only gets "one shot".

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
             <a href="https://sdkclements.github.io/oneShotFront/" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Site</a>
             <a href="https://github.com/sdkclements/oneShotFront" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!-- End of Modal -->

      </div><!-- /col12 -->

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
       <p><img src="images/kicksstarter.png"></p>
       <h2 class="font-thin"><span class="font-semibold">kickSStarter</span></h2>

       <!-- Modal Button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3">
         Information
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">kickSStarter</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
            A website where independent sneaker designers can submit custom designs to showcase their talents to other designers.  Built with Mongo, Express, ReactJS, and NodeJS.

           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
            <a thref="https://github.com/bgalladian/kickSStarter2" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Modal -->

      </div><!-- /col12 -->
     </div><!-- /row -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /slide3 -->


 <!-- === Slide 4 - Skills === -->
 <div class="slide story" id="slide-4" data-slide="4">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row title-row">
    <div class="col-12 font-thin">See what <span class="font-semibold">I can do</span></div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row line-row">
    <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row subtitle-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 font-light">Most important skill is being able to learn <span class="font-semibold">Fast</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->


   <div class="row content-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
     <h2 class="font-thin"><br><span class="font-semibold" >Front End</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">
      <p>HTML</p>
      <p>CSS</p>
      <p>JavaScript</p>
      <p>jQuery</p>
      <p>AngularJS</p>
      <p>React</p>
      <p>Bootstrap</p>
      <p>Materialize</p>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
     <h2 class="font-thin"><br><span class="font-semibold" >Back End</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">
      <p>Ruby</p>
      <p>Rails</p>
      <p>Mongoose</p>
      <p>Sinatra</p>
      <p>NodeJS</p>
      <p>Express</p>
      <p>PostGresQL</p>

     </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
     <h2 class="font-thin"><br><span class="font-semibold">Other</span></h2>
     <h4 class="font-thin">
      <p>GitHub</p>
      <p>Heroku</p>
      <p>Windows</p>
      <p>MacOS</p>
      <p>Microsoft Office Suite</p>
      <p>Google Docs</p>
      <p>User Stories</p>
      <p>Wire Framing</p>

     </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5">


    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /slide4 -->


 <!-- === Slide 5 === -->
 <div class="slide story" id="slide-5" data-slide="5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row title-row">
    <div class="col-12 font-thin">Take a look at my <span class="font-semibold">Resume</span></div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row line-row">
    <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row subtitle-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 font-light">
     <embed src="images/resume.pdf" width="100%" height="1000px"></embed>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->

  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /slide5 -->



 <!-- === Slide 6 / Contact === -->
 <div class="slide story" id="slide-6" data-slide="6">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row title-row">
    <div class="col-12 font-light">Leave me a <span class="font-semibold">message</span></div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row line-row">
    <div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div class="row subtitle-row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 font-light">You can find me  anywhere, just push a button and I'm there</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
   <div id="contact-row-4" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-hover-text">
     <p><a target="_blank" href="#"><i class="icon icon-phone"></i></a></p>
     <span class="hover-text font-light ">(240)-200-2418</span></a>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-hover-text">
     <p><a target="_blank" href="mailto:bedig.galladian@gmail.com"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i></a></p>
     <span class="hover-text font-light ">Feel free to email me!</span></a>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-hover-text">
     <p><i class="icon icon-home"></i></p>
     <span class="hover-text font-light ">Washington, DC</span></a>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-hover-text">
     <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bgalladian/"><i class="icon icon-linkedin"></i></a></p>
     <span class="hover-text font-light ">Lets Connect on LinkedIn!</span></a>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 with-hover-text">
     <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.github.com/bgalladian"><i class="icon icon-github"></i></a></p>
     <span class="hover-text font-light ">Check out my work on Github!</span></a>
    </div><!-- /col12 -->
    <div class="col-sm-1 hidden-sm">&nbsp;</div>
   </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /Slide 6 -->

</body>

<footer>
 &copy; Bedig Galladian 2017
</footer>

 <!-- SCRIPTS -->
 <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack-v=2.1.5.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

 <!-- fancybox init -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 var lis = $('.nav > li');
 menu_focus( lis[0], 1 );

 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  padding: 10,
  helpers: {
   overlay: {
    locked: false
   }
  }
 });

});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: can you send me full code ?

Comment: I just added it for you.

Comment: modal open or not ?

Comment: the modal opens, but the links inside wont work.  Any link I attempt to put in the model does nothing.  I can right click and open in new window, but just clicking it does nothing.

Comment: Did you get any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Nope, not errors.

Comment: try this <a href="https://bgalladian.github.io/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button" target="_blank">Go to Site</a>

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" >
     <ContentTemplate>
          ... your code here ...
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

inside

```
<div class="modal fade" ...
```

while wrapping

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
```

Result:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">US Citizenship Quiz</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            Small sampling of the US Citizenship Test built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="https://bgalladian.github.io/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Site</a>
                                    <a href="https://github.com/bgalladian/project-01" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Go to Code</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
```

Comment: Didn't work, just made the second modal not open and links still dont work in the modal.

Comment: what about wrapping the entire thing in an asp:Panel with     runat="server"